# Adding custom arguments to Jackson deserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a custom deserializer. But I want to be able to pass additional arguments.  For example

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=CustomDeserializer.class, customParm=value)
MyObject obj;
```

How can I pass in my custom parameter on the annotation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot add your own parameters to `@JsonDeserialize`,
because you can't alter Jackson's implementation of this annotation.

However, you can achieve your goal in a slightly different way.
You can invent your own annotation (let's call it `@MyAnnotation`)
and use that alongside with the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation on your property:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
@MyAnnotation(customParm = "value")
private MyObject obj;
```

The implementation of the annotation is pretty straight-forward.
The following example annotation just defines a single `String` parameter.

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    String customParm();
}
```

Then you can access the parameters of `@MyAnnotation` from within
your deserializer as follows.

- As usual your deserializer needs to implement the `deserialize` method
  where you do the actual deserialization of the property.
- Besides that your deserializer needs to implement
  the [`ContextualDeserializer` interface](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/ContextualDeserializer.html)
  and implement the [`createContextual` method](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/ContextualDeserializer.html#createContextual(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanProperty)).
  Here you configure your deserializer (by getting the `customParm` from `@MyAnnotation`).
  Jackson will call this method before the actual deserialization.

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyObject> implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private String customParm = null;

    public CustomDeserializer() {
        super(MyObject.class);
    }

    public CustomDeserializer(String customParm) {
        super(MyObject.class);
        this.customParm = customParm;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property)
            throws JsonMappingException {
        MyAnnotation myAnnotation = property.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
        if (myAnnotation != null) {
            String customParm = myAnnotation.customParm();
            // return a new instance, so that different properties will not share the same deserializer instance
            return new CustomDeserializer(customParm);
        }
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public MyObject deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // do your deserialization (using customParm)
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm having trouble reconciling the way you have constructors with other examples I've seen.  it doesn't quite work.    What I've seen is the following:

public DateDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public DateDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

This worked fine for me before I added createContextual().  

But you are passing in the class of the deserializer and it seems to cause it to hang.  Are you sure that the argument to the superclass constructor should simply be hard-coded as the class of the deserializer?

Comment: Sorry, I mispoke.  I meant the class of the data object, not the deserializer

Comment: Got it working.  My problem was that I was throwing an IOException if certain conditions weren't satisfied.  That caused the code to just hang, even though the method's signature has IOException.  Throwing a RuntimeException worked fine

Answer (score 1):

According to previous solution I create my custom date deserializer.And it works for me.

First create your annotaition.

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomDateFormat {
    String customDateFormat();
}
```

Second create your serializer class.

```
public class CustomDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<DateTime> implements ContextualDeserializer {

private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
private String customDateFormat = null;

public CustomDateDeserializer() {
    this(null);
}

public CustomDateDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
    super(vc);
}
public CustomDateDeserializer(Class<?> vc, String customDateFormat) {
    super(vc);
    this.customDateFormat = customDateFormat;
}

@Override
public DateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
    String date = jsonparser.getText();
    try {

        if (!Util.nullToBosluk(date).equals(""))
            return new DateTime(getDateFormat(this.customDateFormat).parse(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return null;
 }

@Override
public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property)
        throws JsonMappingException {
    CustomDateFormat customDateFormatAnn = property.getAnnotation(CustomDateFormat.class);
    if (customDateFormatAnn != null) {
        String customParam = customDateFormatAnn.customDateFormat();
        return new CustomDateDeserializer(this._valueClass, customParam);
    }
    return this;
 }

private DateFormat getDateFormat(String customDateFormat) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(customDateFormat))
        return new SimpleDateFormat(customDateFormat);
    else
        return this.formatter;
 }
}
```

Finally use your new annotation in your code.

```
...
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
DateTime invoiceDate;
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
@CustomDateFormat(customDateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
DateTime createDate;
...
```