# Can you have multiple annotations on a Java record?

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I have a java record that I am deserialising with a custom `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer` and inside that record I have a field of type `BigDecimal`. Because of some weird project contextual things, in the input string, the `BigDecimal`'s input string is Base64 encoded and I need to also include the scale so I can convert String -> BigInteger -> BigDecimal. To make this more general I found a solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67665044/4960314) to create a custom annotation to hold the scale value and then use it in the `JsonDeserializer`.

My Custom Annotation is:

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BigDecimalScale {
    int value();
}
```

So my record looks like:

```
 public record InputRecord(String name,
                           @JsonDeserialize(using = BytesToBigDecimalConverter.class)
                           @BigDecimalScale(value = 2)
                           BigDecimal cost){}
```

My JsonDeserializer:

```
public class BytesToBigDecimalConverter extends JsonDeserializer<BigDecimal> implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private int scale = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    public BytesToBigDecimalConverter() {
        super();
    }

    public BytesToBigDecimalConverter(int scale) {
        super();
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        String encodedDecimal = jsonParser.getText();

        var decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedDecimal);
        var bi = new BigInteger(decoded);

        // If we have an @BigDecimalScale
        if(this.scale != Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            return new BigDecimal(bi, Integer.valueOf(this.scale));
        }

        return new BigDecimal(bi);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext deserializationContext, BeanProperty beanProperty) throws JsonMappingException {
        BigDecimalScale bigDecimalScale = beanProperty.getAnnotation(BigDecimalScale.class);
        if (bigDecimalScale != null) {
            int scale = bigDecimalScale.value();
            // return a new instance, so that different properties will not share the same deserializer instance
            return new BytesToBigDecimalConverter(scale);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

However, when I was debugging my deserializer it only ever had a single annotation (the `@JsonDeserialize()`). As a test I decided to convert my record to a regular class

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ToString
    static class InputClass {
        private String name;
        @JsonDeserialize(using = BytesToBigDecimalConverter.class)
        @BigDecimalScale(value = 2)
        private BigDecimal cost;
    }
```

It's a spring boot project so was just testing it with:

```
    @GetMapping
    public void testing() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String input = "{" +
                "\"name\":\"Testing Fiddle\"," +
                "\"cost\":\"Bdw=\"" + // Should be 15.00
                "}";

        InputRecord ir = new ObjectMapper().readValue(input, InputRecord.class);
        InputClass ic = new ObjectMapper().readValue(input, InputClass.class);
        System.out.println(ir);
        System.out.println(ic);
    }
```

The output:

```
InputRecord[name=Testing Fiddle, cost=1500]
TestController.InputClass(name=Testing Fiddle, cost=15.00)
```

So my question is, can I not have two annotations on a single field for a Java record?
jackson-databind Version: 2.15.3

Comment: Is `@BigDecimalScale` your annotation? If so, can you post its source too? Specifically if you have the right `RetentionPolicy`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Apologies, I forgot to add that. I have just updated my question.

Comment: Records are not Java beans so I'm not sure that `BeanProperty` will do what you want it to do on records.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, yes, you can.

Longer answer, it seems your problem is with the annotation's target. It should be `ElementType.RECORD_COMPONENT`.

The correct target for a record property is `ElementType.RECORD_COMPONENT` see [java specs for `@Target`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.1).

In this complete reproducible example, you will see that `Annotation2`  and `Annotation3` are correctly added to the `cost` record property while `Annotation1` is not.

```java
package org.example;


import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (var c : InputRecord.class.getRecordComponents()){
            System.out.println("Anotations of " + c + ":");
            for (var a : c.getAnnotations()) {
                System.out.println("  " + a);
            }
        }
        
    }
}


@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Annotation1 {
    int value();
}

@Target({ ElementType.RECORD_COMPONENT })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Annotation2 {
    int value();
}

@Target({ ElementType.RECORD_COMPONENT, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Annotation3 {
    int value();
}

record InputRecord(String name,
                           @Annotation1(value=1)
                           @Annotation2(value=2)
                           @Annotation3(value=3)
                           BigDecimal cost){}
```

The output is:

```
Anotations of java.lang.String name:
Anotations of java.math.BigDecimal cost:
  @org.example.Annotation2(2)
  @org.example.Annotation3(3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about `RECORD_COMPONENT`, it almost got me across the line, the issue now is I am trying to access the annotations via the `BeanProperty` of the `createContextual` method. And another comment suggests this wont work because it is not a Bean. I can't seem to find a way to access the classes annotations like you have done in your answer here (I have the BigDecimal member, not the InputRecord)

Comment: Did you test this in your project and it failed? I mean, was not that annotation present after cahnging it to `RECORD_COMPONENT`?

Comment: It seems jackson databind is not informing the annotation of the record components, I don't know if it is a bug, or they just don't plan to support that yet